# CSS Grid - child elements going over the width of the parent container

Tags: html, css

[image: Intended Effect]

I want to achieve the effect above using CSS Grid - child items should flow downwards if the width can't contain everything. However what I am getting instead is the child elements going over the set width of the parent container.

(The width of the Item needs to be `120px` instead of dynamic width)

[image: Instead]

Below is my code:

```
<div style="width: 50%;">
    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 1fr)); grid-gap: 10px;">
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; border: 1px solid blue;">Item</div>
       <div style="width: 120px; background: red; font: #fff; grid-column-start: -1; grid-row-start: -1;">Act</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The arrangement outcome should look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: I should have used `grid-column-end: -1` instead of `grid-column-start: -1`.

I think by using the latter, it was creating an additional column not considered to begin with.

Comment: Indeed, `grid-column-start: -1` places the item outside of the explicit grid (the layout you defined) and into an implicit grid. [Grid layout using line-based placement: Counting backwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid#counting_backwards)